# JQuery - how to stop a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function test(counter) {
      if(counter==4)
        {
              counter=0;
         }
      if(counter==0)
         {
            //various stuff

          }

          counter = counter + 1;
         setTimeout(function () { test(counter); }, 7000);
  }

 $(document).ready(function () {

 test(0);

 });
 </script>
```

So when the page loads the `test(0)` function is running.

But i have this link `<a onclick="test(1)" rel="2" href="#">` that calls the same function again, having as a result to have the same function running twice.

Is there a way to stop the function that is already running and then start the new one??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the result of `setTimeout()`, and use it with `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: Thanks with the reply! But how this would help me?

Comment: @mathew: Where you have the `setTimeout()` call, that function returns an identifier for the timer that is setup by it (`timerID = setTimeout(...);`).  In order to cancel a pending timer event, you have to clear it, using `clearTimeout(timerID);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(counter) {
      if(counter==4)
        {
              counter=0;
         }
      if(counter==0)
         {
            //various stuff

          }

          counter = counter + 1;



          var quit;
          //decide whether to continue
         if(!quit)setTimeout(function () { test(counter); }, 7000);


  }
```